# Função de JavaScript quebrando a imagem

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Olá;

Estou tendo um projeto do Técnico, e nele tem uma lista de jogos, quero fazer que quando passe o mouse por cima a imagem aumente, com isso tenho o seguinte:

```
foreach ($lista as $jogo){
    echo ('
        <div class="quad-Jogo box">
            <img onmouseover="Aumenta(this)" onmouseout="Normaliza(this)" src="img/'.$jogo['imagem'].'" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
            <a href="detalharesenha.php?cod='.$jogo['cod'].'">Veja mais</a>
        </div>
    ');
}
echo ('
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Aumenta(img){
            img.style.width = "110%";
        }
        function Normaliza(img){
            img.style.width = "100%";
        }
    </script>
');
```

Mas quando a imagem aumenta, o resto das outras imagens quebram, e ficam todas tortas.
O que posso fazer para arrumar isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa de JavaScript para isso. Pode usar o `scale()` do CSS com `:hover`:

```css
.zoom:hover{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); /* Safari */
   transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<img class="zoom" width="100" src="http://www.personal.psu.edu/oeo5025/jpg.jpg">
<img width="100" src="http://www.personal.psu.edu/oeo5025/jpg.jpg">
```

Coloque uma classe específica para isso na imagem (no exemplo, criei a classe `.zoom`). Como você quer que a imagem aumente `10%`, logo o valor do `scale` será `1.1`.

O `scale` aumenta (ou reduz) o elemento sem alterar a área que ele ocupa na página, portanto, não irá afetar a disposição dos outros elementos próximos.

Se quiser colocar um efeito suave, pode usar `transition`:

```css
.zoom{
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
   transition: transform .3s ease;

}

.zoom:hover{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); /* Safari */
   transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<img class="zoom" width="100" src="http://www.personal.psu.edu/oeo5025/jpg.jpg">
<img width="100" src="http://www.personal.psu.edu/oeo5025/jpg.jpg">
```

Uma boa documentação sobre o `transition` você **[encontra aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)**. Veja também sobre o `scale()` **[neste link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)**.